# If someone has a Canadian PR, can he pay tuition fees at domestic rate?

Tags: canada, pr, education

Every Canadian tertiary institution maintains different rates for domestic students and international students for the payment of tuition fees.

If someone has a Canadian PR (Permanent Residency), can he pay tuition fees at domestic rates? Or, is this facility offered only for full citizens?

Comment: In general it is illegal and could be unconstitutional to treat citizens and permanent residents differently, unless an important justification exists (e.g. public services, participation in elections). They are not usually considered as foreign nationals.

Comment: Also note that some provinces (e.g. Newfoundland and Quebec) has different layers of domestic tuition fees giving even more preferential treatment to residents of a province, as defined by the province.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Permanent residents are not charged as international students.  For example, Queen's University [says](https://www.queensu.ca/registrar/international-students):

> If you are not a Canadian citizen, Permanent Resident (Landed Immigrant), or a person registered as Indigenous within the meaning of the Indian Act, you are charged the international fee (see Undergraduate Tuition Fees - International or Graduate Tuition Fees - International).

(Hyperlinks removed)

It goes on to say:

> A number of exemptions may apply to International students. A short description of each of these categories follows. Each of these cases must be examined individually by fee assessment staff in the Office of the University Registrar, in Gordon Hall.
>
> International students who qualify for an exemption are charged domestic fees (see relevant Domestic fees schedule on the Fees section of our website. International students with questions about their fees or payments can contact the Office of the University Registrar by telephone at 613-533-6894 or by fax at 613-533-2068.

(Hyperlinks removed)